# JScript error: Cannot assign to a function result

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In my application I am trying to hide a table based on a condition.
I am using  simple javascript function to hide the table.

the function is failing on the following line

```
if ((image1.trim() = '') && (image2 != '1')) {
```

giving error

> 'Microsoft JScript runtime error: Cannot assign to a function result'.

Here is the code.

Html code:

```
 <table id="tblImage" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding:2px 0px">
            <tr>                
                <td>
                    <div id="otherImages"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
     </table>
```

Javascript function:

```
function DisplayTable() {
    var image1 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_image1').value;
    var image2 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_image2').value;
    if ((image1.trim() = '') && (image2 != '')) {
         jQuery('#tblImage').hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: `=` is not the same as `==` ;) And to push it one step further. Keep using the strict versions of the comparison operators [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if ((image1.trim() = '') && (image2 != '')) {`

should be

```
if ((image1.trim() == '') && (image2 != '')) {
              this__^
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using `=`, but you should use `==`:

```
if ((image1.trim() == '') && (image2 != '1')) {
```

Basicaly `=` means assign value and `==` means *is equal to*. This generates error because it is not possible to assign value to function (which happens where, you're trying to assign value to `trim()`).

Answer (score 2):

You are using `=` (*assignment*) instead of `==` (*equals*) in the folowing `if` statement, resulting in the `assignment to a function` error. Use the following instead:

```
if ((image1.trim() == '') && (image2 != '')) {
     jQuery('#tblImage').hide();
}
```